# Internationalization -- impact on other modules?

Tags: 6, i18n-l10n, search

I installed the internationalization module because the site I'm developing is in a different language, but I can no longer index the site in Drupal's search engine, and Tagadelic isn't working either. I'm assuming all of these issues are somehow related but I'm actually not entirely sure... is there anything specific I need to do when I install the internationalization module to ensure other modules keep working are compatible with other languages?

Comment: Please define "not working". Does tagadelic give you errors? If so, care to post these errors here?

Answer (score 2):

The i18n modules can have a huge effect on a site, as they integrate with a large number of modules. Many modules for example deal with taxonomy terms and displaying them, so they all need to be compatible with i18n.

The main problem is that many content elements (like menus, taxonomies, ..) are not designed to be translatable or even just language aware. So the i18n project needs to alter a lot of things and build data structures and API's on top of those provided by core.

Also, there have been a number of API changes unfortunately, so it's possible that the modules you mentioned have a broken i18n integration due to that.

You need to provide more details on what exactly isn't working to get more help than this. You can also try to check the issue queue of the broken modules to see if there already is an issue for this and if not, open one.

Answer (score 1):

With i18n each module might have it's own sort of i18n config that you might have to set.  Some modules you have add i18n settings via config variables in settings.php, some have settings that you have to set for each language that you have installed. Views you might have to include filters for language, or current user's selected language and what not, there can be a ton of configuration depending on what your requirements are. Check out the README of each module and more times than not if it's a widely used module it'll have some section telling you what to do when you're using i18n.

I wish there was a simple answer to this but as it stands it's just a case by case basis per module. The best thing you can do is include i18n from the very beginning when you start building your site, instead of building your site then enabling i18n later. I say this because now you have to deal with all of the configuration and optional development associated with i18n along with fixing errors and maintaining the site, which can be a hassle to juggle.